# Place blockquotes using PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to modify the single.php file in my wordpress theme to specifically place any blockquotes I make in the post in the same position (which is outside the main content)

```
            <tr><td>
            <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>         
    <div class="author"><?php echo ' - Listed by ';the_author_meta( 'nickname', $userID ); ?></div>
            </td></tr>
            <tr><td>

            </td></tr>
```

*For example I want it to sit in the second table cell.

I obviously don't know php so any help would be great.
Thanks.

Edit - So here is an example of how the page currently looks. http://listble.com/?p=296 You can see the quote sitting below the table (which is written into the php not the post) containing the title, author and feature image. Basically I want Blockquotes to automatically place into a cell below the author and title.

Comment: please define more what you want output where you want write something on post

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't understand your question. Do you mean, where specifically do I want to place the blockquotes?

Comment: @AndyBlanc you have to tell more about what you want to achieve then it would be great to resolve this thread; show us some kind screen-shoot etc.

Comment: @webomnizz I've edited the question with more detail and a url.Thanks for being patient.

Answer (score 1):

according to your link http://listble.com/?p=296, i don't think it is possible to show only `blockquote` in `<td></td>`. Because you are getting your related content with `the_content()` function, and this function returns all the inserted data not the chunks of data.

But with CSS i did a little trick,
place the following CSS code in `blockquote`,

```
float: right;
top: -30px;
```

[image]